# remove html code from thjis tweet

Tags: python, html, twitter

```
original_tweet= 'I luv my &lt;3 iphone &amp; you’re awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  http://www.apple.com”

import HTMLParser

html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

tweet = html_parser.unescape(original_tweet)
```

### I am facing this error in this code. help me to get rid off it.

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-12-58919c61b71f> in <module>()
> ----> 1 tweet = html_parser.unescape(original_tweet)
>       2 tweet
>
> C:\Users\vntja\Anaconda2\ds\lib\HTMLParser.pyc in unescape(self, s)
>     474                     return '&'+s+';'
>     475 
> --> 476         return re.sub(r"&(#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w{1,8}));", replaceEntities, s)
>
> C:\Users\vntja\Anaconda2\ds\lib\re.pyc in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
>     153     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
>     154     a replacement string to be used."""
> --> 155     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
>     156 
>     157 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
    [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
    "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
    before asking a question.

Comment: What do you want to unescape there? There is nothing escaped in the `original_tweet`. If you want to **escape** it, then maybe try `html_parser.escape(original_tweet)`? But there is no HTML code in this string...

Comment: Could you elaborate more as what would you expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of your python script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You're trying to decode something into ASCII that isn't defined in ASCII.